# Barcode Class issue in Magento 2.4.2

Tags: magento2.4.2, barcode

Getting this error
**"Class 'Zend\Barcode\Barcode' not found "** when I upgraded magento to 2.4.2.
It was working fine 2.3.4

This Barcode class I used in My custom Module

Comment: Zend is deprecated. You will have to hunt down the equivalent Laminas class.

Comment: but laminas class should come with magento package. right?

Comment: Yes, mostly likely within vendor/laminas directory. The trick will be finding  the equivalent to the Zend class that you were using. It looks like vendor/laminas/laminas-validator/src/ contains a Barcode class.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue, was you able to fix it?
Zend\Barcode was removed: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/release-notes/backward-incompatible-changes/#application-framework-libraries

The equivalent laminas' class is **Laminas Barcode** https://docs.laminas.dev/laminas-barcode but seems its not included in default packages. Is there a official way to achieve this?